# Modeling Messages between Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modeling

I want to model messages between users, here is the requirement:

1. User has received and sent messages, and should be retrieved by `user.received_messages` and `user.sent_messages`
2. Message has sender and receiver, and should be retrieved by `message.sender` and `message.receiver`.

I have created the User model as:

```
script/generate model User name:string
```

and Message model as:

```
script/generate model Message content:text sender_id:integer receiver_id:integer
```

I have come up with the Message like below, and it works as wish

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sender, :class_name=>'User', :foreign_key=>'sender_id'
    belongs_to :receiver, :class_name=>'User', :foreign_key=>'receiver_id'
end
```

but I don't know how to model the User, any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as in the Message model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

@eric2323223

If you just copy/pasted the code from Milan, then I suspect the error you're seeing is because there's a missing semi-colon in front of 'foreign_key'.

The lines should read:

```
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
```

Kenny

Comment: fixed the typo. thanks. +1 for a good spot ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I made a typo "foriegn_key".